# How to install PyPy3 (2.1, beta) on Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, python

How do I go about installing PyPy3 on Ubuntu 13.04? The download link is here: http://pypy.org/download.html

I've downloaded the Linux 64-bit binary and the .tar.gz source. I'm able to run pypy binary through the terminal, but that's not a very ideal implementation as it requires me to point to the pypy binary directory every time I want to use it.

The source won't really compile, and gives me this error:

```
Building PyPy with JIT, it'll take about 40 minutes and 4G of RAM
rpython/bin/rpython -Ojit pypy/goal/targetpypystandalone.py
/usr/bin/env: pypy: No such file or directory
make: *** [pypy-c] Error 127
```

I'm well aware that PyPy3 is beta software, but I'd like to have a spin with it anyway.

edit: After installing the pypy (Python 2) package provided by Ubuntu, I got a little further with the compilation process. A link to the output: http://pastebin.com/qTMkPsEP

Comment: The latter error is due to missing build dependencies - try `sudo apt-get build-dep pypy` (I think the pypy3 dependencies should be same).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My thanks to chronitis. There were some dependency errors. Correct course of actions:

```
sudo apt-get install \
gcc make python-dev libffi-dev libsqlite3-dev pkg-config \
libz-dev libbz2-dev libncurses-dev libexpat1-dev \
libssl-dev libgc-dev python-sphinx python-greenlet
```

Then:

```
cd PATH/pypy3-2.1-beta1-src/pypy/goal
```

Then you want to build pypy:

```
pypy ../../rpython/bin/rpython -Ojit targetpypystandalone
```

That will take 40 minutes. After compiling is done, you will get a `pypy` or `pypy-c` (I can't recall) file in `PATH/pypy3-2.1-beta1-src/pypy/goal`. Rename this to `pypy3` for your own convenience. Now, this is where I got stuck, as I have no idea how to neatly package this up and install through a .deb file. Instead, I did this:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s "PATH/pypy3-2.1-beta1-src/pypy/goal/pypy3" .
```

This creates a symbolic link (shortcut) to the location of the `pypy3` file. Now, when you type `pypy3` in the terminal, it'll launch. It's not a neat solution, but seeing as PyPy3 is in beta anyway, that'll have to do. If somebody wants to point out how to package the thing up, that'd be magnificent, though.

Comment: Someone has allready [packaged pypy2.x](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=pypy) maybe this gives you an idea how to package it?

Answer (score 0):

To make the package after building see Packaging on http://pypy.org/download.html:

```
cd ./pypy/pypy/tool/release/
python package.py ../../.. pypy-my-own-package-name
```