# How to install PYPY3 on Ubuntu, for newbies?

Tags: software-installation

I want to install pypy3 in Ubuntu. I have read the answer for this question "How to install PyPy3 (2.1, beta) on Ubuntu?" and still have no idea what to do. Could some kind soul please explain it so that even I can understand it :)

Here's what I have done so far:

Went [here](http://pypy.org/download.html)

Read that I had to go [here](https://github.com/squeaky-pl/portable-pypy)

Downloaded: pypy3-2.1-beta-linux_x86_64-portable.tar.bz2

Opened it with the Archive manager (because it seemed like a reasonable thing to do)

Extracted it to desktop/PYPY3

Then desperately tried all the shell commands I came across last night. I will not be able to give a clear account of what I tried and what errors came back, as it is kind of a blur to me at this point.

But I can tell you that I got the Tar thing unpacked at one point and that I have tried running the pypy executable from the command line from the folder containing it, but got this:

```
bash: /usr/bin/pypy: No such file or directory
```

Could someone please tell me what to do. (have read the readme, the install docs at pypy.org and lots of posts)

Comment: Did you have a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/360187/how-to-install-pypy3-2-1-beta-on-ubuntu?

Comment: yes, and I tried to follow the instructions, spent hours on it actually. What was hoping for was a dumbed down version I could follow.

Comment: The answer to that question seems pretty simple, what in it could you not digest- list it explicity?

Comment: I've just re read the question again. He says he is able to run the pypy binary through the terminal. I'm not that far yet. Therefore the rest of the answer is not directly aplicable to me. in the readme of the download it says to run this line  `rpython/bin/rpython -Ojit pypy/goal/targetpypystandalone.py` to install pypy, this gives me a No such file or directory error. I think this is what I need to get working

Comment: I have a similar problem. I've downloaded it into `$HOME`, extracted via `tar` went into `pypy3-v5.10.1-linux64/bin` and tried to run `pypy3`, which is in this folder, but bash tells me `No command 'pypy3' found`

Answer (score 29):

All the answers here are either outdated or unnecessarily complicated.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pypy/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pypy3
```

As simple as that!

See https://launchpad.net/~pypy/+archive/ubuntu/ppa for details.

Comment: The other answers (mine included) are evidently outdated. *pypy3* was not in the *pypy* PPA last year when I was looking into this.

Comment: Unfortunately, this distribution is a pain in the ass. It uses system site-packages and pypy3 -m ensurepip will not work. I suggest to use the tar distribution the first moment you experience any trouble.

Answer (score 5):

This is a portable version of PyPy. It is not installed system wide. You use it like this. After downloading a file lets say to your Downloads folder open your terminal window and run this:

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar xf pypy3-2.1-beta-linux_x86_64-portable.tar.bz2
pypy3-2.1-beta-linux_x86_64-portable/bin/pypy
```

You will get PyPy prompt.

Note that PyPy 3 is not fully done. This is preview version that is inteded for testing.

Comment: This answer works perfectly. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Here's [installing section](http://pypy.org/download.html#installing) of download page from PyPy's website:

> All binary versions are packaged in a `tar.bz2` or `zip` file. When uncompressed, they run in-place. For now you can uncompress them either somewhere in your home directory or, say, in `/opt`, and if you want, put a symlink from somewhere like `/usr/local/bin/pypy` to `/path/to/pypy2-5.10.0/bin/pypy`. Do not move or copy the executable `pypy` outside the tree – put a symlink to it, otherwise it will not find its libraries.

In can be expressed like (excerpt from [snake-tank](https://hub.docker.com/r/saaj/snake-tank) Docker image):

```
wget -q -P /tmp \
  https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/downloads/pypy3-v5.10.1-linux64.tar.bz2 
sudo tar -x -C /opt -f /tmp/pypy3-v5.10.1-linux64.tar.bz2
rm /tmp/pypy3-v5.10.1-linux64.tar.bz2
sudo mv /opt/pypy3-v5.10.1-linux64 /opt/pypy3
sudo ln -s /opt/pypy3/bin/pypy3 /usr/local/bin/pypy3
```

After that you can create virtual environments as usual:

```
virtualenv -p pypy3 some_env
```

Answer (score 3):

Or with `snap`:

```
sudo snap install pypy3 --classic
```

Answer (score 1):

See Bora M. Alper's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1121758/18444) to easily install the PyPy 3 package from a PPA.

---

You can build PyPy 3 from source by doing the following as documented on the PyPy [download](https://pypy.org/download.html#building-from-source) and [build](https://pypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html) pages.

You can either download the source code archive [pypy3-v6.0.0-src.tar.bz2](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/downloads/pypy3-v6.0.0-src.tar.bz2) with the browser or your favorite download utility:

```sh
wget https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/downloads/pypy3-v6.0.0-src.tar.bz2
tar -xjf pypy3-v6.0.0-src.tar.bz2
cd pypy3-v6.0.0-src
```

Or you can download it from the Mercurial repository and switch to the 3.5 branch:

```sh
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy
cd pypy
hg update py3.5
```

PyPy recommends that you build it using PyPy 2 because it'll be faster than using CPython 2.7. Ensure PyPy 2 is installed:

```sh
sudo apt-get install pypy
```

Now install the build dependencies:

```sh
sudo apt-get install gcc make libffi-dev pkg-config zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libsqlite3-dev libexpat1-dev libssl-dev libgdbm-dev tk-dev libgc-dev python-cffi liblzma-dev libncursesw5-dev
```

Run the translation (compilation):

```sh
cd pypy/goal # pypy3-v6.0.0-src/pypy/goal
pypy ../../rpython/bin/rpython -Ojit targetpypystandalone
```

*Even though the shell might not tab-complete `../../rpython/bin/rpython`, it's there. The download guide says it requires 5 GB of RAM and takes about 30 minutes to run. It took 32 minutes on my 4th generation i7.*

Package PyPy so that it can be installed:

```sh
cd ../tool/release # pypy3-v6.0.0-src/pypy/tool/release
pypy package.py --archive-name pypy3-v6.0.0
```

This will create the prepared directory structure under `/tmp/usession-release-pypy3.5-v6.0.0-0`. Copy it to `/opt` and symlink the executable to `/usr/local/bin`:

```sh
sudo mv /tmp/usession-release-pypy3.5-v6.0.0-0/build/pypy3-v6.0.0 /opt
sudo ln -s /opt/pypy3-v6.0.0/bin/pypy3 /usr/local/bin
```

Now you can run PyPy 3 using the command:

```sh
pypy3
```